# C# Error Passing Parameters between forms

Tags: c#, parameters

let me explain the context, I have a form called "Menu" to call another form called "Bill",  I'm using the Bill form  to call SearchClient form. In Bill form I have a datagridview to receive "passing rows" by SearchClient form.

I call Bill by Menu button:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  Bill bill = new Bill();
       bill.Show();}
```

However, I have parameters in Bill class.

```
public Bill(string code, string name, string email)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        grid.Rows.Add();
        grid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = code;
        grid.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = name;
        grid.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = email;

    }
```

I call the "SearchClient" form using Bill button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { SearchClient searchcli = new SearchClient();
        searchcli.ShowDialog();}
```

In SearchClient I have a button to passing rows by a datagridview to another  datagridview (found in Bill)

```
Bill bill = new Bill(grid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), 
            grid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
            grid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString());
            bill.Show();
```

When I run the programm the message error is : Error 'SisStore.Bill' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

I know the error is here, because is missing parameters:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  Bill bill = new Bill();
       bill.Show();}
```

But I just need pass information between Bill and SearchClient. The Menu is just a way to summon the Bill form and later SearchClient. Somebody can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Lot of possibilities here. 1) Make parameters optional, 2) Declare three properties on the Bill form and remove the parameters, 3) Add an event on Search dialog and subscribe to it from Bill.   But remember that when you write _new Bill(.....)_ from Search dialog you are creating a new instance of Bill. The parameters are passed to this new instance not to the Bill instance that calls the Search dialog

Comment: Are those values _required_ for the `Bill` form to function? Can you pass `null` as values or add another constructor with no parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are using the framework quite right, but in your case, couldn't you just set the properties of Bill after you constructed it, like so:

```
public Bill()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void init(string code, string name, string email)
{
    grid.Rows.Add();
    grid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = code;
    grid.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = name;
    grid.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = email;
}
```

In SearchClient:

```
private Bill bill;
public void setBill(Bill bill)
{
    this.bill = bill;
}
```

And then in Menu:

```
private Bill bill;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    this.bill = new Bill();
    bill.Show();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    SearchClient searchcli = new SearchClient();
    searchcli.setBill(this.bill);
    searchcli.ShowDialog();
}
```

Again, in SearchClient:

```
... your button click function ...
{
     this.bill.init(grid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), 
        grid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
        grid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString())
}
```

Comment: Ok, but there are an error in SearchClient button click function (this.bill.init...): An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in SisStore.exe. 
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. What happen?

Comment: you need to call searchcli.setBill(this.bill) before using this.bill.init in SearchClient..

Comment: Right, but when I write searchcli.setBill(this.bill) , the bill of this.bill there are the follow error : does not contain a definition for 'bill' and no extension method 'bill' accepting a first argument of type 'SisStore.Bill' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I had create setBill in SearchClient.

Comment: I  solved using other way and with your informations, thanks for help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your Bill form should have a zero argument constructor.  I suggest the following

```
protected Bill()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public Bill(string code, string name, string email): this()
{
    grid.Rows.Add();
    grid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = code;
    grid.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = name;
    grid.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = email;

}
```

Or you can just keep a zero argument constructor and use object initialisation instead for creating Bill

```
Bill bill = new Bill 
{ 
    code = grid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), 
    name = grid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
    email = grid.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString()
};
```

Comment: I was using the protected Bill() and so I run the program : Error is inaccessible due to its protection level